# Mysql 2 Tables join Limit Result return from both Table

Tags: mysql, join

I have been trying this requirement for few hours but im clueless as im not getting the desired result.

I have two table.

```
**Main Comment Table
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | comments | date_commented | comment_owner | commented_by 
1    hello world  **********        321             123

Child Comment Table
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | mainpostID| child_comment_data           | commented_by |  date_commented** 
1     1          child comment of hello world    456             ********
```

My requirement: 
I want to retrieve the first 10 Main Comment along with Chilcomments for each Main comment. I will like to limit the number of Child comments to 5 for each Main comment.

What i tried:

```
SELECT maincomment.comments, childcomment.child_comment_data 
FROM maincomment
LEFT JOIN childcomment ON maincomment.id = childcomment.mainpostID
AND maincomment.comment_owner = childcomment.commented_by
WHERE maincomment.id = childcomment.mainpostID
ORDER BY dateposted DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Results: Im getting only 10 Maincomments but the number of childcomments are just 1 for each Main comment. What i need is to return 5 childcomments for each of the Maincomment.

Will anyone please help out with some suggestions / query here.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM maincomment
    ORDER BY dateposted DESC
    LIMIT 10
) a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT a.*
    FROM childcomment a
    INNER JOIN childcomment b ON a.mainpostID = b.mainpostID AND a.id <= b.id
    GROUP BY a.id
    HAVING COUNT(1) <= 5
) b ON a.id = b.mainpostID
ORDER BY a.dateposted DESC, b.date_commented DESC
```

This gets the up to the 5 latest child-comments of the 10 latest main-comments. If there are no child-comments for a particular main-comment, the child-comment data will contain `NULL` values.